# Intuitions on understanding system of linear equations as linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

I am looking for an explanation of (in)homogeneity of linear systems of equations from a perspective of linear transformations.

For example, the following connections between linear transformations and linear systems of equations I understand:

---

### 1) If the system is homogenous it has at least $\mathbf{0}$ as a solution.

**Transformation perspective:**

$\mathbf{0}$ is a solution, as $T\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}$ for all linear transformations $T$; trivial from definition of matrix multiplication.
There might be other vectors that $T$ sends to $0$.

### 2) If the system is invertible, is has exactly one solution.

**Transformation perspective:**

If it is invertible, it is a bijective mapping, thus there is exactly one vector that satisfies the system. If there were more, it would not be bijective.

---

So, specifically I would like to understand from a transformations perspective the following:

- From a linear transformations perspective, what does it mean for a system of equatiosn to be homogenous (apart from $\mathbf{0}$ being a trivial member of the nullspace of the transformation.)
- From a linear transformations perspective, what does it mean for a system of equatiosn to be inhomogeneous
- what are free variables from the perspective of linear transformations
- from the perspective of linear transformations why are there infinitely many solutions if there are more variables than equations ( = basis vectors from the point of view of transformation?)

Comment: You understand the notion of rank?

Comment: Yes, it is the number on linearly independent vectors in a matrix, which is the same as the dimensionality of the transformation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your phrase “dimensionality of the transformation?”

Comment: As Randall is suggesting, any linear transformation can be represented as a matrix (which we will designated as A).  If the matrix has full rank then f(x) = Ax is a bijective mapping.  If A does not have full rank, then the null space is non-trivial and for any output, there are infinitely many inputs.

Comment: @amd the number of independent columns/ basis vectors.

Comment: @NicNic8 I don't really see yet how that answers my questions, especially the ones about homogeneity.

Comment: If you understand rank and nullity as you say you do, then take a stab at answering your own questions. Consider the dimension of the image of the transformation and how that relates to the dimensions of the domain and codomain.

Comment: @amd I know that if the transformation matrix is $n \times n$ and is not full rank, it has linearly dependent columns and thus can only map into a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$ where $k < n$. I also know that when there is a zero-row in the matrix, this amounts to at least one column being linearly dependent. Same goes for an $n \times m$ matrix, where $m>n$. But I don't see the relation to my questions; especially not to homogeneity.

Comment: I maybe see though, that free variables correspond to non-zero rank and thus to dimensions lost in the transformation. Depending on how you choose the components of your solution vector in these lost dimensions, the other components need to adjust, but there always are values that fulfill the system of equations/ the transformation equation. But that is very vague to me and not 100% clear why.